# HTML in desktop application load a page with an iframe

Tags: xml, apache-flex, iframe, air, html-parsing

I have a mx:html component in a AIR Desktop Application that load an external webpage into it...

this webpage has an iframe in it and the iframe load (obviously) another page...

I can't figure out how to get the code of the iframe...

If I try to get the webpage content I only retrive the start page like:

File webpage.html

```
<html>
<!-- html code-->
<iframe src="http://host/framepage.html">content default</iframe>
<!-- other html code-->
</html>
```

File framepage.html

```
<div>test test test</div>
```

I'd like to get the string `<div>test test test</div>`

please tell me that there is a way to get the content of iframe (without reloading it)...

**EDIT**

Looking at the response of [Exort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035573/html-in-desktop-application-load-a-page-with-an-iframe/8037347#8037347), using

```
var iFrame:* = domWindow.document.getElementById("myIframe");
```

will return me the iframe, but the content it's not the one I want to...
Using my webpage and framepage example above, the iframe content I will get is

> `content default`

instead of

> `<div>test test test</div>`

It's like as the second page is not loaded, but it's actually be loaded and rendered in the browser window (i tried also using a button so I can delay the search for the iframe content.

Comment: Is the iframe on the exact same domain as the parent project?

Comment: This question is sort of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785823/accessing-an-iframes-contents-in-adobe-air

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much time so this might not be a really deep answer, but the iframe is considered in a window and has a document of its own. You can get it's content with the html DOM with something like this. This is AS3 by the way, event if I'm using '*' as the object types. Using Object type won't work really well here.

```
var domWindow:* = myHTML.htmlLoader.window; //DOM window object

//if you don't have the id, you can get all iframes with getElementsByTagName("iframe")
var iFrame:* = domWindow.document.getElementById("myIframe");

var iFrameContent:String = iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
```

Comment: it won't work, except the fact that the last 2 lines don't give any result, also getting the `iframe` I could not retrieve the data... instead I can get the "text" of iframe that there is on the first page. I edited my post to better clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test it, but the solution is around that. Try inspecting the iframe in debug and see if you can't get the window. From the top of my mind it was contentWindow but it could be something else. I'll see if I can provide you with more details later, sorry!

Comment: NP! I looked into the debug window for at least the entire morning and found nothing useful, so I asked here.. hope someone can help..

Comment: Ah! I found old code on this, I have updated my solution. Hope it works!

Comment: take a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f11.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a3fc7-7fea maybe there's something here

Comment: Wes I looked into it, but it won't work, or I could not achieve it :(

Comment: @Marcx you have not responded on my edit. Have you tried it?? It was working last time I tried it.

Comment: yeah I tried and it did not work... read the edit paragraph I wrote on the question...

Comment: I myself edited my post after you edited yours. The actual html is not in the contentWindow but in the contentDocument object : var iFrameContent:String = iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML

Comment: it won't work either.. I tried again yesterday... I got this error `TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.`